# Output search results to HTML

Tags: javascript, dom

I am creating various projects to help learn as I go. This one is a small web page that allows you to add athletes and then search for them. I created 3 athletes with the same name - When I search for the name, the issue I am having is that the code only displays the last entry. However if I console.log 'output' it does show the correct results. Any pointers would be welcome. :)

```
finder.addEventListener('click',function(){
let find = search.value

const res = data.filter(data => data.firstName === find);
for (let i=0; i < res.length;i++) {
    const list=document.createElement('LI')
  const output = results.innerText =`Here are your details:
    Member Name: ${res[i].firstName}, ${res[i].lastName}, Age: ${res[i].age}, Club: ${res[i].club}, EaNumber: ${res[i].eanum}`
   
   list.append(output)
}
})
```

Comment: Hi, Do you want all the 3 matched entries to be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 const list=document.createElement('li')
```

In this line you are just creating an li component. And with every iteration, that li element is overwritten. So you need to create a list first and then add li elements into the list. try this:

```
var list = document.createElement('ul'); // creates a list
for(let i=0 ; i<res.length; i++){

    var li_item = document.createElement('li'); // creates a list item

    item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(res[i])); // adds text to li 
    
    list.appendChild(li_item); // appends the li item to the list
}
```

And then you can use the list to display data